# Adding all Gmail contacts to Gmail chat

Tags: gmail, chat, google-contacts, google-talk

I want to add all of my contacts to the chat list. I have selected "Show in chat list:">All Contacts, but not all of my contacts are showing there. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing that with Gtalk and Excel:

- by exporting all contacts to `.csv` in GMail.
- and edit them in Excel and add "," to the right column
- from Excel save this as text file
- and by deleting `CR` `LF` all contacts save all contacts to 1 line
- copy and paste them to next step
- I click on <kbd>Add</kbd> button in Gtalk

Answer (score 0):

The *Show in chat list: -> All Contacts* refers to the contacts that are already in your Gtalk list, not to all your Gmail contacts.

Besides, to add a contact to chat, it has to have a Gmail account, otherwise it will not work. You can add a non Gmail contact to your chat list by sending an invitation to him/her, but he/she will just be invited to open a Gmail account.

> If you already have Gmail or Google Talk, visit:
> http://mail.google.com/mail/xxx
> You'll need to click this link to be able to chat with Alex.
>
> To get Gmail - a free email account from Google with over 2,800 megabytes of
> storage - and chat with Alex, visit:
> http://mail.google.com/mail/yyy